# function (){ return fn.apply(me, arguments); } as a callback

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

This recently open sourced code for Monocle.io https://github.com/maccman/monocle has some coffee script/mvc code that I don't understand. If I look at the source in the Chrome console (which shows the JavaScript, not the coffeescript), there is a function like this at the top of each concatenated file, just before the class declaration. For example, the first part of the code that creates Collections is like this

```
    __bind = function(fn, me){ return function(){ return fn.apply(me, arguments); }; };

  $ = jQuery;

  Events = require('events');

  Collection = (function() {
```

In the coffeeScript, however, this function

```
__bind = function(fn, me){ return function(){ return fn.apply(me, arguments); }; };
```

does not appear. It only shows when the code's compiled to JavaScript.

Question 1. Why does that function only appear in the compiled JavaScript?

Moving on, it appears that same function

```
 function (){ return fn.apply(me, arguments); }
```

is getting passed as the callback to many different functions throughout the code. For example, in the Collection class it is the callback passed to the each function.

```
 each: (callback) =>
    @all().promise.done (records) =>
      callback(rec) for rec in records
```

It is also the callback that gets passed to this observer function in the Model class (in the MVC part of the application)

```
observe: (callback) ->
    @on('observe', callback)
```

I understand generally how this function works

```
function (){ return fn.apply(me, arguments); }
```

It just means that the function `fn` is called in the context of `me`, and any arguments passed to it are represented by `arguments`, however, I don't understand how it's working in this application. Why is it generated in the compiled JavaScript when it's not in the original coffeescript, and question 2) is there something about MVC applications that makes it suitable as the callback for all these different functions, or why is it passed as the callback to all these functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us look at a simplified example of the CoffeeScript:

```
class C
    m: => console.log(@)
```

That becomes this JavaScript:

```
var C,
  __bind = function(fn, me){ return function(){ return fn.apply(me, arguments); }; };

C = (function() {
  function C() {
    this.m = __bind(this.m, this);
  }

  C.prototype.m = function() {
    return console.log(this);
  };

  return C;

})();
```

There's your `__bind`. If we look at how it is used then maybe things will be clearer:

```
this.m = __bind(this.m, this);
```

That appears in the `C` constructor function and with it does is replaces the `m` method with the function that `__bind` returns so we effectively have this:

```
var m     = this.m;
var _this = this;
this.m = function() {
    return m.apply(_this, arguments);
};
```

and we see that the `m` method ends always having `this` as the `C` instance regardless of how it is called:

```
c = new C
c.m() # @ (AKA 'this') is `c` inside `m`.
f = c.m
f()   # @ is again `c` inside `f`
```

> [**Demo**](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aclass%20C%0A%20%20%20%20m%3a%20=%3E%20console.log%28@%29%0A%0Ac%20=%20new%20C%0Ac.m%28%29%0Af%20=%20c.m%0Af%28%29) (open your console please)

Compare that with how `m: -> console.log(@)` behaves:

> [**Demo**](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aclass%20C%0A%20%20%20%20m%3a%20-%3E%20console.log%28@%29%0A%0Ac%20=%20new%20C%0Ac.m%28%29%0Af%20=%20c.m%0Af%28%29)

You can see the full generated JavaScript at those two demo links.

So what's going on with this `->` vs `=>` stuff? In CoffeeScript, you use `->` or `=>` to define a function or method. The difference is that [`=>` produces bound functions](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow):

> **Function binding**
>
> In JavaScript, the `this` keyword is dynamically scoped to mean the
>   object that the current function is attached to. If you pass a
>   function as a callback or attach it to a different object, the
>   original value of `this` will be lost. [...]
>
> The fat arrow `=>` can be used to both define a function, and to bind
>   it to the current value of `this`, right on the spot. This is helpful
>   when using callback-based libraries like Prototype or jQuery, for
>   creating iterator functions to pass to `each`, or event-handler
>   functions to use with `bind`. Functions created with the fat arrow are
>   able to access properties of the `this` where they're defined.

Note the discussion of callbacks in that part of the documentation. You're seeing all that binding stuff with `each` because someone wants to be able to say things like:

```
something_that_calls_back(obj.each)
```

and have `this` be `obj` inside `each` when it is called.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Helps a bit. However, this is where I get lost with JS.  What am I looking for in my console when I open those links. Nothing appears automatically in the console. Am I missing something?

Comment: Try hitting the **Run** button in the demos. How much JavaScript do you know?

Comment: ok, I get it, I think. I'm supposed to compare the results of `run` in one console (where the fat arrow preserves context) to the results of `run` in the other console (where the regular arrow loses context), so in fat arrow I get `C {m: function, m: function}` but with regular arrow I get window as context `Window {top: Window, window: Window, location: Location, external: Object, chrome: Object…}`. I've read a lot of JavaScript books and apps, but have trouble with complex applications, so even if I understand these basic points,I've trouble keeping track of these details in big apps.

Comment: The fundamental thing is that `this` inside a JavaScript function depends on how the function is called not how it is defined. Except, of course, in the case of bound functions. That's why `c.m()` and `f()` have different behavior in the `->` version even though `c.m` and `f` are exactly the same function.